# WINAPI: Create new thread on class member function - incompatable parameter type

Tags: c++, winapi, createthread

I've been re-architecting some fairly procedural C++ into something more classy. The original code runs just fine and part of it spins up a new thread to do some file cleaning. The function that does this cleaning is the entry point for the new thread. See code below. NB: This code won't execute, but it shows the principle that worked.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// Structure for passing application data to a new thread.
typedef struct threadData {
    networkShare*   netArchive;
    rig*            rigInfo;
    rigDatabase*    dbConn;
    networkConn*    netConn;
    char*           logBuffer;
} THREADDATA;

// Global handle to a mutex object
// Used to control access to the inter thread log buffer
HANDLE ghMutex;

DWORD WINAPI cleanLocalArchive(LPVOID lpParam) {
    THREADDATA* p_threadData = (THREADDATA*)lpParam;

    // ... Do stuff ...

    return <<something>>;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // Variables for local archive thread
    HANDLE h_CleanerThread = 0;
    THREADDATA* p_threadData = NULL;
    DWORD dwThreadId;

    // Create a mutex with no initial owner
    ghMutex = CreateMutex(
        NULL,              // default security attributes
        FALSE,             // initially not owned
        NULL);             // unnamed mutex

    if (ghMutex == NULL) {
        printf("CreateMutex error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Declare the data structure for passing app setting to a new Thread and populate it.
    p_threadData = DBG_NEW THREADDATA;
    p_threadData->netArchive    = &rigArchive;
    p_threadData->rigInfo       = &thisRig;
    p_threadData->logBuffer     = (char*)malloc(BUF_SIZE);
    p_threadData->dbConn        = &archiveDB;
    p_threadData->netConn       = &netConnection;

    // Initialise p_threadData->logBuffer in case we never put anything else in there.
    sprintf_s(p_threadData->logBuffer, BUF_SIZE, "");

    // Start a new thread
    h_CleanerThread = CreateThread(
        NULL,                   // default security attributes
        0,                      // use default stack size  
        cleanLocalArchive,      // thread function name
        p_threadData,           // argument to thread function 
        0,                      // use default creation flags 
        &dwThreadId);           // returns the thread identifier 


    // ... Do other stuff ...

    return 0;
}
```

I've now refactored the code into classes and the function "cleanLocalArchive" is a member function of the application class AircatFeeder. When I call this member function in the in CreateThread() I get various errors depending on what I do to the code:

As-is: call line = "cleanLocalArchive,"

```
error C3867: 'AirCatFeeder::cleanLocalArchive': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
```

So I add in an ampersand: call line = "&cleanLocalArchive,"

```
error C2276: '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression
error C2660: 'CreateThread': function does not take 5 arguments
```

After some head scratching and Google-Foo I found [this](https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/553051-error-c3867---trying-to-pass-member-function-as-parameter/) link which I hoped would solve the issue. It certainly shed some light on the why. I created a wrapper function outside the class and tried calling that. The function and its call was as follows:

**Function call:**

```
// Start a new thread
    h_CleanerThread = CreateThread(
        NULL,                       // default security attributes
        0,                          // use default stack size  
        trampoline,         // thread function name
        p_threadData,               // argument to thread function 
        0,                          // use default creation flags 
        &dwThreadId);               // returns the thread identifier
```

**Wrapper Function:**

```
DWORD trampoline(LPVOID data) {
    AirCatFeeder* scheduler = static_cast<AirCatFeeder*>(data);
    return scheduler->cleanLocalArchive(data);
}
```

However, I still ended up with the same issues/error messages. Whether I call the member function, or the wrapper function, IntelliSense still reports a similar error message:

```
argument of type "DWORD(*)(LPVOID lpParam)" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE"
```

Hopefully it is now clear what I'm trying to achieve. Can someone please educate me on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Your trampoline should work as-is. There's something else going on.

Comment: The trampoline is missing WINAPI.

Comment: Think I cracked it. I just cast the call to trampoline to type LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE. I'll run a full debug on this bit of code before closing this question. Why does the answer always come to you just after you ask the question?

Comment: Never cast a declaration error away.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I removed it and added the WINAPI call to the function header. Worked a charm. I'd never had known that. I'm familiar with the basics of what adding WINAPI does, but how would I have known to add it here? Because the thread entry function is also defined as that? Because I'm dealing with a windows function (CreateThread)?

Comment: @Ben because `CreateThread()` takes an `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` as input, which is defined as a pointer to a function that uses `WINAPI` (`__stdcall`) as its calling convention.  Obviously, whatever function you pass to `CreateThread()` must match what it is expecting.

Comment: Note that in VC++ at least you can use a stateless lambda as the thread procedure rather than a free function, and it will pick up the calling convention automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer courtesy of Hans Passant. See Comments on question:

**The trampoline is missing WINAPI in its definition.**